# What is the best way to verify cookies are enabled for html 5 (mobile) website using asp.net mvc 3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, html, session-cookies

I know that similar questions have been asked here but I am nevertheless having trouble getting it to work.

I am writing an html 5 website using ASP.NET MVC 3 that is targeted to mobile devices.

I had previously asked [another question about how to store and retrieve expensive data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10421121/how-do-you-pass-expensive-data-from-page-to-page-using-asp-net-mvc-3) and decided to go with Session variables.

I finished the app and started internal testing and all was well until we realized that the web site is not working on some iPhones.  After researching I came to realize that Session variables depend on cookies and that some iPhones ship with cookies disabled by default.

Until I come up with a better solution, I want to check to see if cookies are enabled and redirect to an error page.

I was hoping that ALL of the code to do this could be written in a base controller but I could not figure out how to do it.  So instead I put the following code into the base controller...

```
protected void WriteCookie()
{
    Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("cookie_test"));
}

protected bool CookieCheck()
{
    return (Request.Cookies["cookie_test"] != null);
}
```

Then in a home controller I am calling the WriteCookie method before loading the view.   The view itself has javascript that is redirecting to one of two controllers / actions.  The controller / view that will usually be called (because html 5 could not resolve the location) is the ChangeLocation / Index controller/action.  In there I have the following code...

```
if (!CookieCheck())
{
    RedirectToAction("CookieRequired", "Error");
}
```

Even with cookies disabled it is not redirecting to the above error page.

So what I am looking for is a best practices approach for solving this problem with a fairly complete code sample.

My home controller is pretty much ALWAYS redirecting to another page (in the javascript not the controller).  I have a total of about 4 controllers with a total of about 6 actions.

My ideal would be to solve this problem completely in the base controller.  If not that then I would love for it to work no matter what valid URL is typed (in other words, even if the web app is not entered through Home / Index).  If not that then at least I want what I have shown in my code to work (set the cookie in Home / Index and check for it in the other controller / actions) and work even if the redirect is happening in a controller.

Comment: The simplest way to check for cookies is via JavaScript.

Comment: What Seth said. Check using JS, if it doesn't work -  location.href = 'errorpage.html';
"iPhones ship with cookies disabled by default" - really ? Apple really is different.. often in a wrong way.